# Using a mutable object as a hash key

Tags: c#, hash, .net-4.5, immutability

Imagine the following class used as a parameters object for some complex request.

```
public class RequestParameters
{
    ///<summary>Detailed User-Friendly Descriptions.</summary>
    string Param1 { get; set; } = "Default";
    int? Param2 { get; set; }
    bool Param3 { get; set; } = true;
    ...
    string ParamN { get; set; }
}
```

I want users to be able to create and configure this parameters object as they see fit before handing it off to be used in a request:

```
RequestParameters _filtered = new RequestParameters();
filtered.Param1 = "yellow";
filtered.Param3 = true;
_someInstance.InvokeRequest(_filtered);
```

Once I am processing the request, I wish to cache the result based on the request parameters supplied. It would be trivial to implement some clone method and `IEquatable<RequestParameters>`, and override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` on the above `RequestParameters` class, but the latter is widely regarded as bad practice - `RequestParameters` is mutable, and if an instance were modified after insertion, it could mess with my cache.

On the other hand, I feel like it would be a tremendous amount of code duplication (and a maintenance headache) if I were to implement some sort of `ReadOnlyRequestParameters` copy of this class, just without the setters.

Would it really be so bad to use this class as a cache key if I'm careful to make copies of the instances users send in, and never modify them once inserted into the cache? What alternatives would you propose if you were a developer working with the same objects?

Comment: How about some kind of factory, where you gather all the parameters, possibly changing them along the way and returning an immutable copy of them on demand? Regarding "code duplication" and "maintenance headache": how about using T4 to keep the read/write properties of the factory and the readonly properties of the immutable copy in sync?

Comment: You have three options. (1) fly by the seat of your pants and just use the object as-is and hope no-one mutates it. (2) Implement a `.Freeze()` method that prevents further changes to the object so that you can rely on `GetHashCode`/`Equals`. (3) Create a read-only version of your class.

Comment: Another problem with implementing GetHashCode() over mutable fields is, it's part of the public interface of the (public) class. Clients may wish to store instances in their own Dictionaries or HashSets, and they may be expecting reference-equality behaviour given that the class is mutable.

Comment: @Enigmativity Those were pretty much the only 3 paths I saw as well. As the only dev on this right now, 3 Seems like the most user-friendly option.

Comment: I can guarantee you that the day you're not careful is the day you rip out mutable keys from the cache altogether. Speaking from experience: Don't do it. Ensure the keys cannot change before using them as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of MattE's suggestion, one potential solution (which I may end up using) is a compromise of the `AsReadOnly()` solution (which requires duplicating the class structure and a lot of copy/pasting).

If the primary goal of this class is user-friendly parameterization, and we're okay with its use as a cache key being a second-class citizen, a relatively simple way to implement it is by creating a `GetHashKey()` method. All this method needs to do is return an immutable object on which we can invoke "Equals" and "GetHashCode" - and guarantee that equivalent instances of this object will be treated equal. Tuples do this, but so do [AnonymousTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb397696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which are leaner and easier to create for more than 6 parameters are involved:

```
/// <summary>Get a hashable / comparable key representing the current parameters.</summary>
/// <returns>The hash key.</returns>
public virtual object GetHashKey()
{
    return new { Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, ..., ParamN };
}
```

The returned `AnonymousType` correctly implements

- `GetHashCode()` as a combined hash of each value in the object.
- `Equals()` as a member-wise comparison of each value in the object.

Using this, we essentially produce a snapshot (copy) of the `RequestParameters` object in its current state. We sacrifice the ability to easily reflect on the properties, but make it easy and safe to use them as an Equatable/Hashable cache key without requiring any additional classes.

In my specific case, avoiding additional classes is particularly important as I don't just have 1 parameters class, I have dozens. What's more, many `RequestParameter` classes inherit from each other (as many requests share the same basic parameters). Creating a whole set of "ReadOnly" versions of these classes would be daunting. In this solution, each just has to override `GetHashKey()` to pair its base classes `AnonymousType` with its own additional parameters:

```
public class AdditionalParameters : RequestParameters
{
    ///<summary>Detailed User-Friendly Descriptions.</summary>
    int? Param42 { get; set; };
    ...
    string Param70 { get; set; }

    public override object GetHashKey()
    {
        return new { base.GetHashKey(), Param42, ..., Param70 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always store the parameters in a Tuple once you have gathered them as that is immutable once created....

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion (I upvoted to counter the downvote someone else gave.) So you're thinking like a GetHashKey() method that returns the Tuple? That's not a bad idea. I think the issue with this suggestion is that I have dozens of parameters, so creating an N-Tuple (which would require nested tuples after the 6th parameter) could get ugly, not to mention I'd lose the nice object-orientedness of working with a class with named properties. Still, all in all, not a terrible idea.